# How to call a method of a class from expression in spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

How to invoke a method from spring integration EXPRESSION :

```
<int:chain input-channel="service.activator.out">
           <int:header-enricher>
              <int:header name="LIST_DATA"
             expression="**HERE NEEDS TO CALL A METHOD OF CLASS BY PASSING PAYLOAD**"/>     
         </int:header-enricher>
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 8):

If that method in on some **bean** you should use `beanReference`:

```
expression="@foo.method(payload, headers.bar)"
```

If it is a **static method** you should use `typeReference`:

```
expression="T(com.my.proj.Foo).method(headers.baz, payload.bar)"
```

And provide appropriate parameters based on `Message` as root object of expression evaluation context.

Comment: How do we code this call if the method is in current class expression="@someMethod(payload.someproperty)" , something like this but this does not work.

Comment: What is "current class"? There is no concept like that in SpEL. you can call `static` methods via specif `T` operator. You can call methods from beans. You can call methods from the root evaluation object. You also can use SpEL functions. Nothing more than explained in docs is possible: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions