# Spring Integration expression to verify string contains another string with equals ignore case

Tags: spring-integration

I am using spring integration in my project. I need to verify if one of the nodes value in my response contains a string by ignoring case sensitivity. 
I have to see if the `databaseName` value contains `DB2` by ignoring case sensitivity.

I am using the following expression to verify, but it's not working.

```
expression="T(java.util.regex.Pattern).compile(T(java.util.regex.Pattern).quote('DB2'), T(java.util.regex.Pattern).CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(#xpath(payload, '//databaseName')).find()"
```

I referred the following links before framing my expression:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

[How to call a method of a class from expression in spring Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646343/how-to-call-a-method-of-a-class-from-expression-in-spring-integration)

[How to check if a String contains another String in a case insensitive manner in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86780/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-a-case-insensitive-manner-in)

Am I missing anything in the expression?

Comment: what's wrong with `#xpath(payload, '//databaseName').toLowerCase().contains("db2")` ?

Comment: Yep! Thanks for the response. It works... But I wanted to give a try with other approach. I was just curious to learn using the java methods by typeReference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As per Gary Russell's suggestion, The following expression worked for me.

```
#xpath(payload, '//databaseName').toLowerCase().contains('db2')
```